# "Stealth" interviews

Tags: job-search, interview

I am an assistant professor and was invited to do a "stealth" interview at another university.

Should I really treat this interview as a secret (and risk that others in my department find out through the grapevine), or should I go ahead and tell my department chair now (even though it is just an interview)? What are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: You can "politically" inform you Chair!

Comment: What do you mean by "politically"?

Comment: It really depends on your relationship with your dept and chair + your status and vibe around you in your dept. I'm not a senior faculty member, but could not you say something like the following? you have been invited for an interview => you feel appreciated => you would like to visit the school and have a sense of it => does not mean you ganna take the job!

Comment: Externally it should look like a "departmental research seminar"

Comment: As an assistant professor, doesn't everyone expect you to be on the lookout for another (permanent) position?

Answer (score 16):

There's absolutely no payoff to telling your chair that another university might be interested in you unless and until you have an offer you think you might want to accept.

If an interview visit is confidential or, as you put it, "stealth", everyone involved should know what that means and there should be very little risk that word of your visit will filter back to your home institution.

Comment: If you need/want a letter from your chair, then you need to tell them.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, researchers do move around the globe, travel for research, give interviews, and it's considered pretty normal.  Still, such visits should not violate your contractual obligations.  So, first check your contract.

If you are formally obliged to spend 100% of your time in your workplace, you formally have get an ok from your boss (department head or dean) before going. Or you have to do the visit in your free time, at least, formally speaking.

If you are allowed spend time on travel to other institutions, simply do it: no need to inform anyone. After all, an interview is a particular form of research: yout also talk about your scientific achievements.

Comment: If it is an assistant position and the contract requires spending 100% of the time in the office, and talks, interviews, conferences etc could be visited after formal permission of a "boss" than, it is better to find another place.

Comment: @Greg Sometimes rather old, outdated formal requirements are written into contracts. An oath is an example. In such cases it's better to avoid problems - otherwise you make yourself vulnerable. The competition might be furious.

Comment: An oath in a contract?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo You wouldn't believe it but yes, some old traditional institutions have it.